# Spring Boot [ Maven (Multi-Modules) ] Gerenciamento do application.properties

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

Bom estou com um probleminha tenho um projeto onde estou utilizando um projeto com Maven, Spring Boot. E dentro do maven estou dividindo os modulos [multi-modules] como

ex.: **Persistence e Web**

O modulo **Web** tem dependencia ao modulo **Persistence**. (Os dois fazem utilização do Spring Boot)

Quando eu build (run) o projeto **Web** o *application.properties* é sobreescrito ao compilar dando preferencia ao utilizado no modulo *"pai"* .

Posso de alguma maneira passar as configuração do *application.properties* (**Persistence**), de forma que o *application.properties* (**Web**) herdar-se o do modulo (**Persistence**) e usasse também o seu proprio *application.properties* ?

Ex. application.properties (Web):

Alguma coisa assim que herdasse o datasource

```
spring.recebeUmaTagAquiParaHerdar.datasource = true;
```

Package do Projeto (Three of Project) :

```
| Build
| - pom.xml
| 
| - persistence
| | - pom.xml 
| | - application.properties
|
| - web
| | - pom.xml  //Tem dependência do projeto persistence
| | - application.properties
```

Bem muito obrigada pela ajuda desde já.

Comment: Uma curiosidade: o seu application.properties funciona fora do classpath?

Comment: Olá AndersonB.Magalhães então por padrão o Spring ele não vai funcionar fora classpath mas você pode sim passar um @PropertiesSource se você quiser apontar para um arquivo externo ou algo assim. [Doc Spring link aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)